# Changes in YAWS takes a while to take effect

Tags: erlang, yaws, erlangweb

When I modify a `.yaws` file it take a few (5, 10) seconds for changes to take effect, it it normal and Do I have to keep terminal open while I use YAWS server?

Comment: Modifying a `.yaws` file causes the Yaws runtime to have to recompile it and reload it. This takes time of course, but it shouldn't take as long as you say. What does your `.yaws` file do? If you'd like you can file a [Yaws issue on github](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/issues) and include a test case, and I or another Yaws contributor will have a look.

Comment: I am new to erling and yaws it is unlike apache and php,  your answer make sense, I didn't know that it compiles erling code on run time... thank you!

Comment: Also, you don't need to keep a terminal open if you run Yaws in daemon mode, using the `--daemon` option.

Comment: @SteveVinoski if you can write your comments as an answer I would vote up and mark it as answered !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify a `.yaws` file, Yaws recompiles it to an Erlang `.beam` file, which contains bytecode for the Erlang virtual machine, and reloads it. This won't be instantaneous of course, but it should not take 5-10 seconds; you should [report a Yaws issue](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/issues) in that case, and please include a test case.

As for requiring a terminal, Yaws can run such that it gives you an interactive Erlang shell, or it can be run as a background daemon if you supply the `--daemon` command-line option. Yaws comes with [a number of startup scripts](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/tree/master/scripts) for running it as a daemon on various operating systems.